# Why does the earthengine-api package on conda-forge limit the google-api-python-client package version?

Tags: python, google-earth-engine-python-api, conda

On conda-forge, the latest version of the earthengine-api package (and, I believe, many versions before the latest) requires google-api-python-client >=1.12.1,<2.  However, the [setup.py](https://github.com/google/earthengine-api/blob/v0.1.331/python/setup.py) file for earthengine-api only requires google-api-python-client >=1.12.1.  Does anyone know why this might be the case, and if it could be changed to make the conda-forge package not require google-api-python-client <2?

I would ask this via GitHub, but that directs people to use the [Google Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:184406&type:bug=), and when I tried that, I couldn't find any issues related to the Earth Engine, which didn't seem right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The conda-forge earthengine-api package pins the google-api-python-client package to [>=1.12.1,<2](https://github.com/conda-forge/earthengine-api-feedstock/pull/119) because of a bug ([google/earthengine-api#157](https://github.com/google/earthengine-api/issues/157)) which the ticket states is now [resolved](https://github.com/google/earthengine-api/issues/157#issuecomment-797215745).

The issue [(#201)](https://github.com/conda-forge/earthengine-api-feedstock/issues) you opened on the conda-forge / earthengine-api-feedstock to see if it can be unpinned was accepted and the upper constraint removed.